# How to get object to rotate opposite of cursor?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently have a set of cubes all contained by an Object3D with the origin being the pivot point:
[image]

My goal is to rotate the cube opposite the position of the cursor. For example, if the cursor were on the left side of the cube, then the cube would spin counter-clockwise around the y-axis (green axis). If the cursor were above the cube, then it would spin counter-clockwise around the x-axis (red axis). Currently, I have attempted to implement this by setting up a "mousemove" event listener; however, it only works when the mouse is moving:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    {...rotations}
}
```

Is there a way to implement this in three.js?

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to detect cursor position and then set object rotation to tilt, or if you want to rotate, you can use [mesh.rotate](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotateX)

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove, false);

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    
function onDocumentMouseMove( e ) {  
    
    e.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
      
       
}
    
    
function animate() {
         
            mesh.rotation.set(
                (mouse.y * -0.4),
                (mouse.x * -0.8),
                0,
            )
    
}
```